# Custom icons font not working

Tags: android, fonts

I am using a font family "font_puck" which contains two font files(which are icon font files):

```
<font
    android:font="@font/font_regular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/font_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"/>

<font
    android:font="@font/font_light"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="300"
    app:font="@font/font_light"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="300"/>
```

below is the TextView that using above fontFamily:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_item_icon"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/option_list_item_icon"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font_puck"/>
```

and it is used for a TextView to show icons. I just need to call setText(String iconKey). This works fine with system fonts
And at last I just created the TextView and set the text(text should be the id of the icon font):

```
TextView tvIcon = findViewById(R.id.tvicon);
tvIcon.setText("u");
```

But some user downloaded some custom fonts from the market and use it. then the app just show the key of the icons(just show above "u") instead of the icons themselves.

I guess that the font is overwritten by system new installed font.But how to solve that?

Any one knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to add font file in your project and set it manually to your TextView like :

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");

tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

After that your font should not be replaced by user font.

Comment: add which font? There are hundreds of different font for user to install, how to avoid font in my project not overwritten by user installed font?

Comment: If you set your font in your project's folder and if you set it manually to your textview, it should not be overwritten by font installed by user.

Comment: Can you show your code ? Because if you set typeface manually (like the code i post) it can't be overwritten by user/android default font. (maybe im wrong but i never see that) You have to add the font you want in your project as 'abc.ttf'.

Comment: I edited the description and that is the part related. You can see that there should be nothing strange. Just make the fontFamily---->use the fontFamily in XML and then set the textView text in code.

Comment: And I also try your method of setting the typeface dynamically. The result is the same. Please be noted that the font I am using is a icon font not a common font. The font contains all icons that I needed.

Comment: The font is not a problem, you can set the font you want. (i already use font i created to easily use icon) Im pretty sure if you set Typeface manually tou your textview it can't be overwritten by user. But fontFamily can be. I have made a custom TextView to be able to set custom font in my xml and be sure system or user can't overwrite it. I will post you my CustomTextView.

Comment: can you please show me the code  or an apk? I am wonder if this works on my phone. Btw, I also tried with set a otf font instead of a fontFamily. Nothing changed...

Comment: You can try with the app "GVApp" available on Playstore. The font in flight list should not be user or system font.

Comment: Sorry I cannot download it from play store. Do you have it on github?

Answer (score 0):

My CustomTextView :

```
public class TextViewCustom extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

public TextViewCustom(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setCustomAttributes(context, attrs);
}


private void setCustomAttributes(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewCustom);
    String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewCustom_customFont);

    setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
    a.recycle();
}

public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    try {
        tf = Typefaces.get(ctx, asset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CustomTextiew", "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    setTypeface(tf);
    return true;
}
```

}

Add this to your attr.xml in values folder :

```
<declare-styleable name="TextViewCustom">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And use it in your xml like this :

```
<ch.atipik.ui.TextViewCustom
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:customFont="fonts/myfont.ttf" />
```

My fonts are in "fonts" folder inside "assets" folder.